# Using a UIImage as a path in a maze game

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimage

I am trying to use a `UIImage` as a path for a marble game.  I am using `CoreMotion` and `QuartzCore` to handle moving the marble on the screen.  The `UIImage` is a simple black and white image where the path is black and the rest of the image is a white background.  I have the code to move the marble, but when I try to check the color of the path image beneath it, the animation on the marble stops and it no longer moves.  If I comment out the line of code that determines the pixel color of the Path image the marble moves fine.  What am I missing to keep the marble moving when I check the color of the pixel?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Movement of marble1
    self.lastUpdateTime = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    self.curPoint  = CGPointMake(443, 350);
    self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc]  init];
    self.queue         = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    self.motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = kUpdateInterval;
    [self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:self.queue withHandler:
     ^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
         [(id) self setAcceleration:accelerometerData.acceleration];
         [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(update) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
     }];
}

- (void)update {
    NSTimeInterval secondsSinceLastDraw = -([self.lastUpdateTime timeIntervalSinceNow]);
    self.marble1YVelocity = self.marble1YVelocity - (self.acceleration.x * secondsSinceLastDraw);
    self.marble1XVelocity = self.marble1XVelocity - (self.acceleration.y * secondsSinceLastDraw);
    CGFloat xDelta = secondsSinceLastDraw * self.marble1XVelocity * 500;
    CGFloat yDelta = secondsSinceLastDraw * self.marble1YVelocity * 500;
    self.curPoint = CGPointMake(self.curPoint.x + xDelta,
                                    self.curPoint.y + yDelta);
    [self moveMarble1];
    self.lastUpdateTime = [NSDate date];
}

- (void)moveMarble1 {
    [self collisionWithWalls];
    [self collisionWithBoundaries];
    self.prevPoint = self.curPoint;
    CGRect frame = self.marble1.frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.curPoint.x;
    frame.origin.y = self.curPoint.y;
    self.marble1.frame = frame;
}

- (void)collisionWithWalls {   
    CGRect frame = self.marble1.frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.curPoint.x;
    frame.origin.y = self.curPoint.y;
    NSLog(@"x=%f,y=%f",frame.origin.x,frame.origin.y);
    CALayer *pathLayer = [self.Path.layer presentationLayer];
    //if I comment out the following line the marble moves with no issues on the screen
    NSLog(@"Color of path is %@",[self pixelColorInImage:pathLayer atX:self.curPoint.x atY:self.curPoint.y]);  
}

- (UIColor*)pixelColorInImage:(CALayer*)layer atX:(int)x atY:(int)y {
    UIImage* image=[self imageFromLayer:layer];   
    CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage));
    const UInt8* data = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);
    int pixelInfo = ((image.size.width  * y) + x ) * 4; // 4 bytes per pixel
    UInt8 red   = data[pixelInfo + 0];
    UInt8 green = data[pixelInfo + 1];
    UInt8 blue  = data[pixelInfo + 2];
    UInt8 alpha = data[pixelInfo + 3];
    CFRelease(pixelData);
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:red/255.0f
                           green:green/255.0f
                            blue:blue/255.0f
                           alpha:alpha/255.0f];
}

- (UIImage *)imageFromLayer:(CALayer *)layer{   
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions([layer frame].size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([layer frame].size);

    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return outputImage;
}
```